# Need list of value from same xml root node

Tags: java, mule, dataweave

My situation is like ,I have below text/xml data which is getting from dataweave

```
   <rootMessage>

  <message> 0123      1234          ahdhgahg  </message>

  <message> 0123      1234          ahdhgahg  </message>

  <message> 0123      1234          ahdhgahg  </message>

   </rootMessage>
```

dataweave mapping is like :

```
   rootMessage:{
        (payload.messanger map {
           message:$.Message
           }
         )
       }
```

I have to store all of these messages data in a single txt file.
file structure will be ,like :

```
 0123      1234          ahdhgahg 
 0123      1234          ahdhgahg 
 0123      1234          ahdhgahg
```

how can I make like this format?

Plz suggest something .Thanks

Comment: And what's the question? We will not write the code for you.

Comment: No need your code #Henry . I would like to know how to extract all the nodes of message which are reside under rootMessage node and make a format as above mentioned in txt file.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, firstly you have to refine your DataWeave Expression to surely reflect the Input data structure. e.g.: there is no `payload.messanger` in that structure.

After that evaluate your expression. Make sure to set the output: `%output application/json`, just for evaluation purpose. From current expression you will get a single JSON object with duplicated fields. Which is incorrect.

```
{
  "rootMessage": {
    "message": " 0123      1234          ahdhgahg  ",
    "message": " 0123      1234          ahdhgahg  ",
    "message": " 0123      1234          ahdhgahg  "
  }
}
```

Therefore, your next step is: refine your expression. The expected result should be a list of JSON object.

```
[
  {
    "message": " 0123      1234          ahdhgahg  "
  },
  {
    "message": " 0123      1234          ahdhgahg  "
  },
  {
    "message": " 0123      1234          ahdhgahg  "
  }
]
```

Finally, set the output: `%output application/csv header=false`. Then you'll get the expected result.

Comment: Thanks for your response ,@Sulthony. I have already implemented and it is working fine .I am using different logic instead of your logic.Thank you again .but seems it will also works.